# Auto generate ranges of Examples in Specflow Scenario Outline

Tags: cucumber, specflow

In Specflow, although I know about the `Scenario Outline / Examples` feature, I was wondering if there is a more elegant way to generate ranges and combinations to be used in test cases?

For example, in vanilla NUnit, I can use a [`TestCaseSource`](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestCaseSource-Attribute) or [`Theory`](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Theory-Attribute) to build a generator which I can feed in a large number of test cases into a test.

```cs
private static readonly IEnumerable<int> Numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 50);

[TestCaseSource(nameof(Numbers))]
public void TestFoo(int number)
{
    // Test goes here.
}
```

At present, in my tests, I need to manually create all permutations in my `Examples`, which can be hard to read, and potentially error prone.

```
Scenario Outline: Count things
    Given I'm playing a game of counting
    When I count to <number>
    Then the highest number I should have counted to should be <number>

    Examples:
        | number|
        | 1    | 
        | 2    | 
        | 3    | 
        ...
        | 50    |
```

What I would really like to be able to do would be

```
Examples:
    | number| : Range 1 to 20
```

And even better, create the cartesian product of two sets, i.e.:

```
Examples:
    | number1| : Range 1 to 20
    | number2| : Range 5 to 10

// i.e. 20 x 5 = 100 combinations of the tuple (number1, number2)
```

Is there anyway for me to approach this more elegantly in Specflow?

Comment: Did you try to use the [CombinatorialAttribute](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Combinatorial-Attribute) and the [ValueSourceAttribute](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/ValueSource-Attribute) together?

Comment: Apologies - I shouldn't have tagged NUnit - but you're right, I'm trying to find if there's an equivalent way, from SpecFlow (i.e. in the Cucumber language), to leverage automated data driven capabilities of the underlying testing framework (like NUnit's Theory, Combinatorial, TestCaseSource (with a generated dataset). I've updated tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dynamically generate the range of numbers from two inputs as a step.

For example:

```
Scenario Outline: Count things
    Given I'm playing a game of counting
    When I count from <First Number> to <Last Number>
    Then the highest number I should have counted to should be <Last Number>

    Examples:
        | Description        | First Number| Last Number |
        | Count from 1 to 20 | 1           | 20          |
        | Count from 5 to 10 | 5           | 10          |
```

And then the `When` step can be defined as something like this:

```
[When("I count from (\d+) to (\d+)")]
public void ICountFromFirstNumberToLastNumber(int firstNumber, int lastNumber)
{
    IEnumerable<int> numbers = Enumerable.Range(firstNumber, lastNumber);
    this.countResult = this.Count(numbers);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Cucumber is not designed to for doing this sort of testing. When you are cuking each scenario is going to have a runtime which is one or more orders of magnitude slower than a well written unit test. So generating large numbers of scenarios makes your test suite unusable.

Cucumber is all about using scenarios to create a few basic interactions to drive the development of some functionality. Its not a test tool!

To test exhaustively some aspect of functionality keep on using unit tests.